# Overflow error with OracleClient and C# 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, oracle10g, system.data.oracleclient

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, Oracle Database 10g and the library System.Data.OracleClient. My problem is when i want execute the Procedure in the batabase i get a Overflow error. I was reading and said i need to ROUND or TRUNCT the number, becuase is too big. But i dont have access to the database to change the Procedure. And the values i get is from OracleParameter with Out Direction. Do you have any idea of how i can fix this problem?.

```
objCommand.Connection = objConnection;
objCommand.CommandText = "Procedure_name";
objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
objCommand.Parameters.AddRange(parameters); //parameters is a OracleParameter array. I fill it previously.

objConnection.Open();
objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); //Here throw the exception
```

PS: The procedure works perfect in PL/SQL, and the number with max. digits is "1.66529411764706";

PS2: Again, i don't have permissions to change the procedure. i need to fix this error in visual studio.

PS3: The error is OCI-22053: overflow error. That's all i have from the error :(

Thanks!

```
parameters[0] = CreateParameter(PC_COD_CU, OracleType.VarChar, codCu);
parameters[1] = CreateParameter(PC_COD_EM, OracleType.VarChar, codEm);
parameters[2] = CreateParameter(PN_SACIC, OracleType.Number, ParameterDirection.Output);
parameters[3] = CreateParameter(PN_SAVSF, OracleType.Number, ParameterDirection.Output);
parameters[4] = CreateParameter(PN_MTO_B, OracleType.Number, ParameterDirection.Output);
parameters[5] = CreateParameter(PN_ULT_REM, OracleType.Number, ParameterDirection.Output);
parameters[6] = CreateParameter(PN_AVG_REM, OracleType.Number, ParameterDirection.Output);
parameters[7] = CreateParameter(PN_TO_SEG, OracleType.Number, ParameterDirection.Output);
parameters[8] = CreateParameter(PN_TA_APL, OracleType.Number, ParameterDirection.Output);
parameters[9] = CreateParameter(PN_TA_D, OracleType.Number, ParameterDirection.Output);
parameters[10] = CreateParameter(PN_DEV_ULT, OracleType.Number, ParameterDirection.Output);
parameters[11] = CreateParameter(PC_TO_F_OBL, OracleType.VarChar, ParameterDirection.Output);
parameters[12] = CreateParameter(PC_TO_F_VCF, OracleType.VarChar, ParameterDirection.Output);
parameters[13] = CreateParameter(PC_TO_F_VSF, OracleType.VarChar, ParameterDirection.Output);
parameters[14] = CreateParameter(PN_RA_MIN_VIG, OracleType.Number, ParameterDirection.Output);
parameters[15] = CreateParameter(PC_PE_MIN_SPP, OracleType.VarChar, ParameterDirection.Output);
parameters[16] = CreateParameter(PC_IND_CON_RES, OracleType.VarChar, ParameterDirection.Output);
parameters[17] = CreateParameter(PC_NUM_RES, OracleType.VarChar, ParameterDirection.Output);
parameters[18] = CreateParameter(PN_VA_NO_RES, OracleType.Number, ParameterDirection.Output);
parameters[19] = CreateParameter(PC_ME, OracleType.VarChar, ParameterDirection.Output);
parameters[20] = CreateParameter(PN_GA_SEP, OracleType.Number, ParameterDirection.Output);
parameters[21] = CreateParameter(PC_TO_TRA, OracleType.VarChar, ParameterDirection.Output);
parameters[22] = CreateParameter(PC_TO_BO, OracleType.VarChar, ParameterDirection.Output);
parameters[23] = CreateParameter(PN_PSEG_NO_D_MIN, OracleType.Number, ParameterDirection.Output);
parameters[24] = CreateParameter(PN_PSEG_NO_D_AVG, OracleType.Number, ParameterDirection.Output);
parameters[25] = CreateParameter(PN_PSEG_AJU_S_MIN, OracleType.Number, ParameterDirection.Output);
parameters[26] = CreateParameter(PN_PSEG_AJU_S_AVG, OracleType.Number, ParameterDirection.Output);
parameters[27] = CreateParameter(PN_PSEG_AJU_D_MIN, OracleType.Number, ParameterDirection.Output);
parameters[28] = CreateParameter(PN_PSEG_AJU_D_AVG, OracleType.Number, ParameterDirection.Output);
parameters[29] = CreateParameter(PN_PAJU_AU_S, OracleType.Number, ParameterDirection.Output);
parameters[30] = CreateParameter(PN_PAJU_AU_D, OracleType.Number, ParameterDirection.Output);
parameters[31] = CreateParameter(PN_PRP, OracleType.Number, ParameterDirection.Output);
parameters[32] = CreateParameter(PN_PJAN, OracleType.Number, ParameterDirection.Output);
parameters[33] = CreateParameter(PN_MON_TO_CAM, OracleType.Number, ParameterDirection.Output);
parameters[34] = CreateParameter(RETURN_VALUE, OracleType.Number, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
```

All the parameters name are strings previously set.

Comment: Could you add the piece of code that set parameters?

Comment: What is the `Overflow error`? Stack overflow, Arithmetic operation overflow? Provide full information about exception including stack trace and inner exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

If you can determine which output parameter is the problem, you can try this hack.  Instead of calling the SP directly from ADO.net, execute a SQL statement which contains an anonymous PL/SQL block that calls the SP, with a function to modify the out parameter (trunc, round or cast).  Example Query:

"BEGIN PROCEDURE_NAME(?,?,?,TRUNC(?),?,?); END;"

Answer (score 0):

Change your query so all columns with a higher precision number are rounded to the decimals you need.

Example:

Select ROUND(estimated_cost, 2) From `<your table>`